# Problems with drawing custom background on Canvas (Android)

Tags: java, android, canvas, background, android-custom-view

I'm trying to draw custom background to my CustomView which extends LinearLayout.

Here is my onDraw() method:

```
int mPositionX = 0;
int mPositionY = 0;
final int viewWidth = getMeasuredWidth();
final int viewHeight = getMeasuredHeight();

mPath.moveTo(mPositionX, mPositionY);
mPositionX = viewWidth;
mPath.lineTo(mPositionX, mPositionY);
mPositionY = viewHeight;
mPath.lineTo(mPositionX, mPositionY);

//draw bottom triangles
for(int i = 0; mPositionX >= 0; i++){
    mPositionX -= HALF_BORDER_STEP;
    mPositionY = i%2 == 0 ? mPositionY - BORDER_HEIGHT : mPositionY + BORDER_HEIGHT;
    mPath.lineTo(mPositionX, mPositionY);
}

// move to left bottom corner
mPositionX = 0;
mPath.lineTo(mPositionX,mPositionY);
mPath.close();

canvas.clipPath(mPath);
canvas.drawPath(mPath, mCheckPaint);
super.draw(canvas);
```

I have 2 problems.

First of all my custom background does not shown if i won't set any background, so i did android:background="@color/transparent" in my xml.

Second problem is that, after i add some views via `.addView(View view)`, my background disappeares.

I have tried to call `invalidate()` but still nothing.

What do i do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

To solve my problem i should have added `setWillNotDraw(false);` which means that my View does drawing on its own. [Android Dev Docs.](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setWillNotDraw(boolean)) After this I missed one more method calling: `mPath.reset();` just before redrawin in my `onDraw(Canvas canvas);` That's it.